# Migrating to OAuth for uploading war file to Google App Engine using ant

Tags: java, google-app-engine, ant, oauth-2.0, google-client-login

`Google App Engine` deprecated client login and moved to `OAuth`. This effects uploading the app(may be war file) to `Google App Engine` as it requires authentication. If ant update is used via AppCfg it throws an error -

> "java.lang.RuntimeException: Bad authentication response: 404 Not
>   Found Unable to update app: Bad authentication response: 404 Not
>   Found"

There are few solutions available for `maven` but not for `ant`.

Answer (score 0):

This issue is fixed by moving to latest Google App Engine version(1.9.34). Latest appcfg update command asks for the OAuth by default. If you are running this command in a remote server(headless browser environment) make sure you run - 'unset DISPLAY'. Otherwise authorisation fails trying to open a browser.

Ref links:

1. [Passwordless Login](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/uploadinganapp#Passwordless_Login_with_OAuth2)
2. [Java awt headless](http://leshazlewood.com/2009/08/26/linux-javaawtheadless-and-the-display-environment-variable/)